# How to resize a table column without changing the sizes of the other columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table that I've added a bunch of interactive behaviors to (addable, removable, movable columns, rename columns, etc).  The last piece of the puzzle is resizable columns.  I have it mostly working by allowing the user to click within 5px of a  border and then dragging the mouse.  My problem is that when a column is resized, the other columns grow or shrink to compensate and keep the table at its width.  My desired behavior is to instead grow (or shrink) the table by the amount that the column is resized and to not adjust any of the other column widths.  Is this possible with CSS/JS?

Comment: I think you may have to calculate the width of each column and keep that static (in pixels say) as you resize the one column the user is interacting with. So the idea would be to react to onresize for the document, such that you can resize the columns accordingly, if they are meant to keep proportions.

Comment: The resize will touch two columns in some cases right? Unless you are limiting it to the left-most or right-most columns.

Comment: No the resize should ever only touch one column (the one on the left of the border being dragged).  The table itself should grow or shrink as the column does.

Comment: this should work, if all columns have a fixed width but the table itself has no width defined.

Comment: @Jared hey can you please provide me with the code to re-seize the columns of HTML table!!! I was going to post a new question for it!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```